# Numbers / number

Tags: word-choice, countable-nouns

[image: A line chart with the title "International Tourist Arrivals (millions)". On the y-axis, a range from 0 at the bottom to 100 at the top in increments of 10. Across the x-axis, years from 1995 to 2010 in 5 year increments. In the legend, Brazil, Egypt, Malaysia, France, and USA are listed. USA is consistently above 70. France increases sharply from 30 tying with USA near 85 at year 2010. Malaysia increases nearly linearly from 20 to about 45. Brazil and Egypt run closely together, also linearly, from both about 9 to Egypt at 15, and Malaysia at 13]

By looking at the graph above, should numbers or number be used in this context?

> Overall, the **numbers** of international tourists arrived in these five countries had increased over the period
>
> Overall, the **number** of international tourists arrived in these five countries had increased over the period

Comment: Number of tourists - remove arrived or change to arriving or change arrived in to visiting

Comment: I think you need to give at least a complete sentence here. Number / numbers are sometimes interchangeable, as a collective (_January sees record-setting number of tourists_ / _Tunisia expects new political stability to attract record numbers of tourists this year_ : internet) and then it's a matter of style rather than correctness. I'd use 'arriving' rather than 'arrived' too.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the grammar - using arriving instead of arrived.

Comment: Hi Edwin, so you are suggesting either of them is correct? I just want to be safe in my exam....

Comment: "The number of tourists from these five countries have increased" (the total number when you add up all five countries). "The numbers of tourists from these five countries have increased" (the number of tourists from each country has increased, not just the total). In the second case, it's better to say "The number of tourists from each of these five countries has increased". In the first case "The total number of tourists from these five countries has increased".

Comment: Skeptic: 'Being safe in your exam' and 'being correct' often mean different things, sadly. I'd choose 'numbers' here to reflect the number arriving in country A, the number arriving in country B ... (so I don't say here "I'd choose 'numbers' here to reflect the numbers arriving in country A, the numbers arriving in country B ...", though I wouldn't even mark this wrong). But I'm not marking your exam. Traditionally, 'the number' was favoured, I believe, and you've probably got traditionalist exam moderators. This is the forum (hopefully) for correct English, not exam advice.

Comment: The use of -ed forms and -ing forms in participial clauses is rather idiosyncratic. _Overall, the numbers of international tourists arrested in these five countries increased over the period ..._ is fine. Obviously, 'arresting' doesn't work here. 'Arrived' is not often used in such a construction, though there are examples: _Arrived at the station, we found we must wait till half past five_ (H B Stowe). Far more commonly used are 'Having arrived at the station ...', and, with a slight shift of meaning, 'Arriving at the station ...'. 'Arriving' (over extended time) works with your example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use "number of" if you follow it with "is/was". Likewise, "numbers of" is acceptable if coupled with "are/were". The first way of phrasing is statistically more common as shown by this Google Ngram, showing written occurrences since 1800:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=numbers+of%2C+number+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnumbers%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumber%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to vote up but I couldn't, anyway this is useful

Comment: No problem. You can check mark it as correct if you find it  a satisfactory answer, though.